# Is JavaScript clearInterval asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, synchronization

I have the code below.

```
var intervalId;

function myCallback() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://bla.html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            if (intervalId) {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
            }

            if (data && data.result) {
                return;
            }

            alert(data.result);
        }
        , timout: 2000
    });
}

function callInterval() {
    intervalId = setInterval(myCallback, 5000);
}

callInterval();
```

The problem is that the "clearInterval(intervalId)" doesn't seems to invalidate the interval at this right time because the message alert is shown twice.

So here is my question, is *clearInterval(intervalId)* asynchronous?

Comment: The AJAX request is probably taking more than a second.  Why aren't you using `setTimeout`?

Comment: Actually, I'm using `setTimeout`. I didn't put it in the question. My interval executes every 5 seconds, and I've used a timeout of 2 seconds.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I mean, what is the goal? it doesn't really make much sense to use an interval to repeat an http call. I guess the goal is to execute an http call every X seconds, as long as one is not running already, but this code doesn't really serve this purpose.

Comment: the message is shown twice because you clear the interval when you get the response not when you start the request. This means that during the latency since the first response, the interval is still starting ajax requests

Comment: Sorry guys, I've edited the code. Now you can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The point is not about being the `clearInterval` sync or async.

In your code you start the interval the first time, and then after every second you execute your `myCallback`.

Clearing the interval when you get back a response, means that during the time that the ajax request is performing, the interval is still running and will start new ajax requests.

Comment: Your answer is concise, but the alert is shown multiple times. I've used "twice" but it is shown as many time as my browser keeps open.

Comment: as I said above, it depends on how you manage the `clearInterval`